# Would the same chain of calls on a mock always return the exact same mock object?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, monkeypatching

**Code:**

```py
from unittest.mock import Mock

mock = Mock()

print('mock.f():', id(mock.f()))
print('mock.f().g().h():', id(mock.f().g().h()))
print('mock():', id(mock()))
print('mock().f():', id(mock().f()))
print()

print('mock.f():', id(mock.f()))
print('mock.f().g().h():', id(mock.f().g().h()))
print('mock():', id(mock()))
print('mock().f():', id(mock().f()))
print()

print('mock.f(1):', id(mock.f(1)))
print('mock.f(2).g(3).h(4):', id(mock.f(2).g(3).h(4)))
print('mock(5):', id(mock(5)))
print('mock(6).f(7):', id(mock(6).f(7)))
print()
```

**Output:**

```
mock.f(): 4483288208
mock.f().g().h(): 4483354192
mock(): 4483368976
mock().f(): 4483708880

mock.f(): 4483288208
mock.f().g().h(): 4483354192
mock(): 4483368976
mock().f(): 4483708880

mock.f(1): 4483288208
mock.f(2).g(3).h(4): 4483354192
mock(5): 4483368976
mock(6).f(7): 4483708880
```

**Observation:**

The output shows that a specified chained function call on a mock always returns the same object within the lifetime of a program regardless of how many times we make that call.

For example, the first call to `mock.f().g().h()`, the second call to `mock.f().g().h()`, and even the third call with different arguments `mock.f(2).g(3).h(4)` return the exact same object.

**Question:**

- Can we rely on this behavior? Is it guaranteed that within the lifetime of a program, `mock.f().g().h()` would return the exact same mock object?
- Is it guaranteed that even the same chain of calls with different arguments, e.g., `mock.f(2).g(3).h(4)` would also return the same object as a `mock.f().g().h()`?
- Are both these things documented somewhere?

**Background:**

The reason why I am asking this is so that instead of writing code like this:

```py
from urllib import request
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

with patch('urllib.request.urlopen') as mock_urlopen:
    mock_urlopen.return_value = Mock()
    mock_urlopen().getcode.return_value = 200
    assert request.urlopen('').getcode() == 200
```

I can write code like this insted:

```py
from urllib import request
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

with patch('urllib.request.urlopen') as mock_urlopen:
    mock_urlopen().getcode.return_value = 200
    assert request.urlopen('').getcode() == 200
```

The examples above are too simple only for demo purpose. I wanted to keep self-contained examples. But if I could rely on this feature, it would become very convenient when the chain of function calls are long. That's why I am looking for some sort of reference or documentation that shows that I can rely on this behavior.

Comment: They aren't the same object; they are different objects, created on demand, reusing object identities of older, no-longer-accessible objects.

Comment: @chepner How is that in the bottommost code example `request.urlopen('').getcode` behaves exactly like how I configured `mock_urlopen().getcode` to be even though I never configured `mock_urlopen` to return a specific mock object when called? If they are really different objects created on demand, I would expect `request.urlopen('')` to return a different mock object whose `.getcode` would be another mock object that is *not* configured with `.return_value = 200`. Yet it behaves like it is configured to return `200`. How is that happening?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I commented too soon. I believe for the same mock object, it is indeed true that the same attribute access will produce an internally cached object. From the documentation, "Accessing the same attribute will always return the same mock."

Comment: I will let someone with more credibility than I have at the moment provide an answer. :)

Comment: @chepner That quote from the documentation is helpful. In addition to "Accessing the same attribute will always return the same mock", I guess what I am looking for is an authoritative source that says something like, "*Calling* the same attribute will always return the same mock."

Comment: Calling an attribute is just getting the return value of its `__call__` attribute, that is, `mock()` is "shorthand" for `mock.__call__()`, and `mock.__call__` is going to be the same value each time.

Comment: A simple point: As you can use `call_count` to get the called count of a `Mock` object. If it doesn't return the same object, how could you implement this? And there are many similar functionalities actually rely on this behavior.

Comment: @chepner @Sraw So if you guys agree that the same chain of calls always return the same object, then I wonder why https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html has this example: `mock_backend.get_endpoint.return_value.create_call.return_value.start_call.return_value = mock_response
` when this could simply have been `mock_backend.get_endpoint().create_call().start_call.return_value = mock_response`

Comment: Actually the assertion `assert mock_backend.mock_calls == call_list`will fail if you do that.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the file `lib/python3.7/unittest/mock.py`

```py
def __getattr__(self, name):
    if name in {'_mock_methods', '_mock_unsafe'}:
        raise AttributeError(name)
    elif self._mock_methods is not None:
        if name not in self._mock_methods or name in _all_magics:
            raise AttributeError("Mock object has no attribute %r" % name)
    elif _is_magic(name):
        raise AttributeError(name)
    if not self._mock_unsafe:
        if name.startswith(('assert', 'assret')):
            raise AttributeError(name)

    result = self._mock_children.get(name)
    if result is _deleted:
        raise AttributeError(name)
    elif result is None:
        wraps = None
        if self._mock_wraps is not None:
            # XXXX should we get the attribute without triggering code
            # execution?
            wraps = getattr(self._mock_wraps, name)

        result = self._get_child_mock(
            parent=self, name=name, wraps=wraps, _new_name=name,
            _new_parent=self
        )
        self._mock_children[name]  = result

    elif isinstance(result, _SpecState):
        result = create_autospec(
            result.spec, result.spec_set, result.instance,
            result.parent, result.name
        )
        self._mock_children[name]  = result

    return result
```

As you can see the object is cached in `_mock_children` dict. And hence every call will return you the object. But the data will be updated. That you can see by running below code

```py
from unittest.mock import Mock

mock = Mock()

mock.a(10)
mock.a.assert_called_with(10)
mock.a(2)
mock.a.assert_called_with(10)
```

and the result

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../workbench.py", line 8, in <module>
    mock.a.assert_called_with(10)
  File ....lib/python3.7/unittest/mock.py", line 834, in assert_called_with
    raise AssertionError(_error_message()) from cause
AssertionError: Expected call: a(10)
Actual call: a(2)
```

So, yes the object will be same, but the object will have updated values